# Renaming fields after a JOIN takes time?

Tags: apache-pig

In the following code, how much does renaming fields after a join hurt the computation time of the script? Is it optimized in Pig? Or does it really go through every record?

```
-- tables A: (f1, f2, id)  and B: (g1, g2, id) to be joined by id
C = JOIN A BY id, B by id;
C = FOREACH C GENERATE A::f1 AS f1, A::f2 AS f2, B::id AS id, B::g1 AS g1, B::g2 AS g2;
```

Does the `FOREACH` command go through every record of C? If yes, is there a way to optimize?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it optimizes - see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/perf.html#multi-query-execution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't worry about optimizing this, there may be a slight overhead in renaming the fields, but it won't trigger an addition Map/Reduce job. The field projection will occur in the reducer after your `JOIN`.

Consider the two pieces of code and the Map Reduce plans given by [`explain`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#explain) below.

#### Without Renaming

```
A = load 'first' using PigStorage() as (f1, f2, id);
B = load 'second' using PigStorage() as (g1, g2, id);

C = join A by id, B by id;

store C into 'output';

#--------------------------------------------------
# Map Reduce Plan                                  
#--------------------------------------------------
MapReduce node scope-30
Map Plan
Union[tuple] - scope-31
|
|---C: Local Rearrange[tuple]{bytearray}(false) - scope-20
|   |   |
|   |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-21
|   |
|   |---A: New For Each(false,false,false)[bag] - scope-7
|       |   |
|       |   Project[bytearray][0] - scope-1
|       |   |
|       |   Project[bytearray][1] - scope-3
|       |   |
|       |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-5
|       |
|       |---A: Load(hdfs://location/first:PigStorage) - scope-0
|
|---C: Local Rearrange[tuple]{bytearray}(false) - scope-22
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-23
    |
    |---B: New For Each(false,false,false)[bag] - scope-15
        |   |
        |   Project[bytearray][0] - scope-9
        |   |
        |   Project[bytearray][1] - scope-11
        |   |
        |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-13
        |
        |---B: Load(hdfs://location/second:PigStorage) - scope-8--------
Reduce Plan
C: Store(hdfs://location/output:org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage) - scope-27
|
|---POJoinPackage(true,true)[tuple] - scope-32--------
Global sort: false
----------------
```

#### With Renaming

```
A = load 'first' using PigStorage() as (f1, f2, id);
B = load 'second' using PigStorage() as (g1, g2, id);

C = join A by id, B by id;
C = foreach C generate A::f1 as f1,  -- This
                       A::f2 as f2,  -- section
                       B::id as id,  -- is
                       B::g1 as g1,  -- different
                       B::g2 as g2;  --

store C into 'output';

#--------------------------------------------------
# Map Reduce Plan                                  
#--------------------------------------------------
MapReduce node scope-41
Map Plan
Union[tuple] - scope-42
|
|---C: Local Rearrange[tuple]{bytearray}(false) - scope-20
|   |   |
|   |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-21
|   |
|   |---A: New For Each(false,false,false)[bag] - scope-7
|       |   |
|       |   Project[bytearray][0] - scope-1
|       |   |
|       |   Project[bytearray][1] - scope-3
|       |   |
|       |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-5
|       |
|       |---A: Load(hdfs://location/first:PigStorage) - scope-0
|
|---C: Local Rearrange[tuple]{bytearray}(false) - scope-22
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-23
    |
    |---B: New For Each(false,false,false)[bag] - scope-15
        |   |
        |   Project[bytearray][0] - scope-9
        |   |
        |   Project[bytearray][1] - scope-11
        |   |
        |   Project[bytearray][2] - scope-13
        |
        |---B: Load(hdfs://location/second:PigStorage) - scope-8--------
Reduce Plan
C: Store(hdfs://location/output:org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage) - scope-38
|
|---C: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-37
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][0] - scope-27
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][1] - scope-29
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][5] - scope-31
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][3] - scope-33
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][4] - scope-35
    |
    |---POJoinPackage(true,true)[tuple] - scope-43--------
Global sort: false
----------------
```

The difference is in the Reduce plans. Without renaming:

```
Reduce Plan
C: Store(hdfs://location/output:org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage) - scope-27
|
|---POJoinPackage(true,true)[tuple] - scope-32--------
Global sort: false
```

versus with renaming:

```
Reduce Plan
C: Store(hdfs://location/output:org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage) - scope-38
|
|---C: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-37
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][0] - scope-27
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][1] - scope-29
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][5] - scope-31
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][3] - scope-33
    |   |
    |   Project[bytearray][4] - scope-35
    |
    |---POJoinPackage(true,true)[tuple] - scope-43--------
Global sort: false
```

In short, there will be other things you can optimize in your script before worrying about renaming. Since you'll be going through every record anyway because of the `join`, renaming will just be a cheap extra step.